# Bokeh data source has columns of inconsistent lengths

Tags: javascript, bokeh

I am trying to create an interactive line chart using Bokeh. Javascript is used to select the correct data from the database. It basically selects the rows, I want to display in the line chart. I have drafted the Python/JS code from examples I found online, but needed to update due to newer versions / appreciated functions. Somewhere along, I probably made a mistake and after staring for several hours, I haven't found a solution.

The problem boils down to population two columns in the ColumnDataFrame used, as they aren't populated with my code (don't know why). These columns are `index` and `level_0`. Both aren't part of the input database.

Here is part of my code:

```
// filter lines.
// iterate over all lines:
for (var m = 0; m < line_renderers.length; m++) {
    // clear out renderer's old data source
    console.log("Vooraf", line_renderers[m].data_source.data);
    line_renderers[m].data_source.clear();
    // iterate over all rows in 'master' data source for this line... 
    var i = 0;
    for (var n = 0; n < line_renderer_source_subsets[m].data.index.length; n++) {
        // save the ones matching the selected criteria...
        if (line_renderer_source_subsets[m].data['Jaar'][n] == jaar_select.value) {
            // and for each field we're tracking, put the field/value combination to this line's data source
            for (var f in fields_to_update) {
                var field = fields_to_update[f];
                line_renderers[m].data_source.data[field][i] = line_renderer_source_subsets[m].data[field][n];
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

The line_renderer_source_subset contains the 'master source' and I want to populate line_renderers with the filtered data from this 'master source'.

I tried adding column names `index` and `level_0` to the fields_to_update, so they would be populated in the loop. It didn't do anything. I reshuffled the code several times, didn't help. Console output clearly shows that `line_renderers` contains columns 'index' and 'level_0' which are empty.